# Как получить значение переменной из url в blade

Tags: php, laravel

есть url - /public/articles/20/edit где 20-это переменная
в blade я делаю проверку если url такой-то то вывожу одно если то другое .Как получить эту переменную?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вот так решил свою проблему с помощью View::make

```
public function edit($id){
        $article=Article::find($id);  
        $categories=Category::all(); 
        View::make('admin.main', $id);
        return view('admin.articles.edit' ['article'=>$article,'categories'=>$categories]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Если вы правильно настроили роут (с переменной), то в контроллер, который исполняет этот роут, передается переменная. Её нужно передать в blade.

> Here is an example of a basic controller class. All Laravel controllers should extend the base controller class included with the default Laravel installation:

> namespace App\Http\Controllers;
>
> use App\User;
>   use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
>
> class UserController extends Controller
>   {
>       /**
>        * Show the profile for the given user.
>        *
>        * @param  int  $id
>        * @return Response
>        */
>       public function showProfile($id)
>       {
>           return view('user.profile', ['user' => User::findOrFail($id)]);
>       }
>   }
>
> We can route to the controller action like so:
>
> Route::get('user/{id}', 'UserController@showProfile');

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/controllers#basic-controllers

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так

routes.php

```
Route::get('/public/articles/{article}/edit', ['as' => 'public.article', 'uses' => 'PublicController@article']);
```

---

App\Http\Controllers\PublicController.php

```
public function article($article)
    {
        $article = Post::latest('post_id')->where('posts.post_id', '=', $article)->get();
        if(empty($article)){
          return view('errors.404'); // если то другое
        }
        return view('public.article', ['article' => $article]); // url такой-то то вывожу одно
    }
```